# Is people plural?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I've been struggling trying to understand if "people" is singular or plural. I mean, I've read both everywhere. Is it Ok to say "people is going crazy" or "people are going crazy"? Which takes me to another question, Is it correct "This people is going crazy" or "these people are going crazy"?

Comment: If there is only one going crazy, then it's "This **person** is going crazy." Short answer is that _people_ is the plural for _person_.

Comment: @J.R. yes. Definitely... unless you're using poor English... there are certainly some vernaculars that would say "People is going crazy".

Comment: People *can* take the plural (s) if you are referring to more than one population: "The peoples of Asia, Africa, and Latin America are...." Oh, someone has just posted an answer including that bit of info.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you have read "everywhere". Every English language dictionary provides a very clear definition of the noun _people_, as well as example sentences which demonstrate how it is used, and in _exactly_ the same way as you have done in your question. What did you not understand about those dictionary entries?

Comment: The word "people" that you are asking about is a plural-only noun, meaning that it requires a plural verb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: People is **plural**. The correct way to phrase it would be "people are going crazy".

Longer answer: There is a specific circumstance when the word **people** is used with a singular sense. It's when it's being used to describe an entire nation/tribe. This is the only time the word **people** can have the plural form of **peoples**; any other time, the word is plural and hence can have no plural form. For example:

> The island's **peoples** have spoken.

As stated in the comments, the plural word **peoples** refers to multiple groups of people (as seen in my example above). It also has a "singular sense", in which it refers to *a people* as one body. Here is an example:

> Americans are **a patriotic people**.

[This site](http://www.pearsonlongman.com/ae/azar/grammar_ex/message_board/archive/articles/00048.htm) explains the people/peoples thing very well.

Comment: You beat me to it.  It might be worth clarifying that the plural "peoples" applies when there are multiple groups, each of which you would apply "people" to in the singular sense.

Comment: In the link you provided, this example is given: "The Portuguese people **have** chosen a new president, where the plural verb "have" is used. But in your virtually identical example, you have used the singular "has".

Comment: @BillJ Thanks! I misunderstood my own quoted site, but I fixed my example.

Answer (score 1):

People is plural.
Person is singular.

"These people are going crazy." is the correct usage.

Comment: Ok, but what about "Maya people was one of the greatest"?

Comment: @MilenkaClaure so why didn't you include that observation in your question, to begin with?